# How to deal with performance bottlenecks in Stochastic Vehicle Routing Problem with Benders' decomposition?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, stochastic-programming, benders-decomposition, c++

I've been working on solving a stochastic vehicle routing problem using Benders' decomposition with CPLEX in C++. Initially, my implementation struggled with larger instances, but I've made significant progress by implementing enhancement strategies such as reformulation of the subproblems according to [Fischetti et al.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-010-0365-7) (2010) and partial Benders' decomposition as described by [Crainic et al.](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/trsc.2020.1022) (2021).

However, I've encountered a bottleneck in my approach. When using partial Benders' decomposition, the master problem becomes complex, leading to longer solve times of the CPLEX solver for each iteration of the master problem. On the other hand, if I don't use partial Benders' decomposition, the master problem lacks scenario information, resulting in a high number of feasibility cuts and iterations, until feasible solutions are found.

In general, the one with partial Benders' decomposition seems more promising though, having better performance so far. The only problem is, due to the exponential complexity of VRPs, it reaches a threshold where it needs 20–30 minutes to solve each master problem instead of seconds, like before.

I'm seeking advice on how to overcome this issue. Has anyone faced a similar problem? At this point, small improvements would be enough for our practical use case, since I am not far off the instance sizes that we aim to solve.

Since with partial Benders' decomposition, the solver taking too long to solve the master problem is the bottleneck, could maybe Gurobi work better? Or are there general methods to speed up the solver?

Fischetti et al. (2010): https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-010-0365-7

Crainic et al. (2021): https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/trsc.2020.1022

Comment: Thanks for noticing, just changed that.

Comment: I assume your master problem is an LP. Are you doing "one tree" Benders (adding cuts in a callback during a single solve) or solving the LP from scratch each time? If the latter, are you adding the Benders cuts as ordinary constraints or lazy constraints?

Comment: My MP is an IP (binary decisions variables, like they come in a standard VRP setting, i.e. decision if a node is served by a vehicle or not, or if an edge is traversed by a vehicle or not). 
I do not use callbacks so far and I add constraints the ordinary way. I don’t resolve the MP from scratch though, I add the new cuts and then resolve the problem using the cplex.solve() command. Do you think I could achieve better performance using callbacks? I’ve heard about that method, but I’m not familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling cplex.solve() after modifying the model restarts the solver from the root node. Using callbacks would allow you to modify the model and then pick up from where you left off, so long as the changes to the model did not alter the feasibility of previously found incumbents.

You can do Benders with either legacy or generic callbacks, but the newer generic callbacks are generally preferable (albeit a bit trickier to implement, due to thread safety concerns). I believe there's at least one Benders example shipping with CPLEX that uses callbacks, and I wrote a [blog post](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2017/11/benders-decomposition-with-generic.html) quite a while back providing an example (including Java source code). Using generic callbacks allows CPLEX to continue to use dynamic search (disabled when using legacy callbacks), which typically helps.

If using the one tree approach (solve MP, solve subproblem, add cut(s), repeat), you might want to consider adding the Benders cuts as lazy constraints rather than standard constraints. It will allow CPLEX to set them aside if they have not been binding for a while, which might speed up the master solve if you are piling up zillions of cuts.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. I will look into it. So far, I've basically treated CPLEX as a black box solver, not really putting much time into researching exactly what it does. Looks like it is time to change that.

Comment: Changing the cuts to lazy constraints requires considerably less alteration of code (see the addLazyConstraints method in the IloCplex class) than does the one-tree approach, so you may want to try it first. The one-tree approach is, I suspect, more likely to provide significant gains in the time (but, as with all things MIP related, you never know until you try).

Comment: Thanks, I will keep it in mind. Will try out lazy constraints first! Very helpful from you, that you further explain it. Especially since getting into callbacks seems quite complicated at first glance.

Comment: I just changed the addition of cuts so that they will all be added as lazy constraints. On first tests, I now receive the warning: "No solution found from 2 MIP starts" while solving the MP. Also, when the program is finished, I receive another warning: "Lazy constraints freed during column deletion". Is this anything to worry about?

Comment: And for clarification: I do not add manual MIP starts so I have no idea where that is coming from suddenly.

Comment: I'm not positive, but it is possible that (a) you have advanced starts turned on and (b) CPLEX tries to start from the previous ending solution each time you invoke solve again. That might explain the MIP starts message, which would not worry me. As for the other message, I can see how deleting a column might make a constraint containing it irrelevant (perhaps implied by other constraints), allowing CPLEX to drop that constraint. Presumably the columns being deleted were dropped during presolve.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'll look further into it. But at least the solutions seem to be correct. By the way, for first tests adding cuts via lazy constraints instead of adding them as normal constraints seems to speed up the algorithm by a lot!

Comment: Quick follow up regarding the warning: If I manually set the advanced start switch to 0 (off), the warnings disappear. So you were right! But, in that case, my master problem takes longer to solve. So I guess it is true that the warnings stem from the fact that I use a single model for the MP, then, after adding cuts, I invoke cplex.solve() again. So I guess I will live with the warnings to achieve better performance.

Comment: I have one more, hopefully last, question to you. While using lazy constraints has certainly accelerated my implementation, the problem described in my original post still holds. With partial BD, I can't solve larger instances, since the MP retaining some scenarios is slow to solve with the CPLEX solver. But if I don't use partial BD, the process of generating feasibility cuts takes too long. Do you think trying out callbacks and implementing Branch-and-Benders-Cut that way is worth a try to tackle my issue? Or will it not speed up the solution process of the MP?

Comment: This is hard to predict. Using callbacks typically reduces master problem iterations, since you are not starting from scratch each time. That might speed up either or both of your approaches. Would it cut down on time spent in the subproblems generating cuts? Perhaps, but I would say not likely. If your subproblems are LPs, there is yet another option. Recent versions of CPLEX have built-in support for Benders, meaning you can use annotations in the model to tell it which variables belong to which subproblems and then turn it loose without having to code callbacks yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your assessment! So far the time spent solving the SPs (they are LPs) has been negligible. I've tried out the CPLEX integrated version of Benders', it is super slow though. Both with the 3/FULL parameter, as well as if I provide the decomposition with the 1/USER parameter.